# Connecting containers with Kubernetes running in a single Vagrant VM

Tags: docker, vagrant, kubernetes

I'm developing in a virtual machine (centOS in Vagrant) running multiple containers. I need to set up a container orchestrator within the VM. A list of containers:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ docker-compose -f /vagrant/docker-compose.yml ps
         Name                        Command               State                     Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
vagrant_django_1          /run-mod_wsgi-express.sh         Up       8000/tcp
vagrant_ers-build_1       bash /ers/startup.sh             Up       35729/tcp
vagrant_jupyterhub_1      /srv/run_jupyterhub.sh           Up       8081/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp
vagrant_mongodb_1         /usr/bin/mongod                  Up       27017/tcp
vagrant_proxy_1           /run-httpd.sh                    Up       0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
vagrant_python-volume_1   /bin/bash                        Exit 0
vagrant_static_1          /run-httpd.sh                    Up       80/tcp
vagrant_websocket_1       bash -c source activate tr ...   Up       8473/tcp
```

My understanding is that I run a "master" on the host, and connect each container to the master.

If nodes = container, the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#44-joining-your-nodes) says to ssh into each container and run the `kubeadm join` command. The issue is you can't ssh into containers; Executing `/bin/bash` on each container is the closest thing to SSH, but kubeadm, docker, and systemd isn't installed in each container.

If nodes != container, then I'm not sure how to connect within a single VM.

Do I have to create a second VM as the "master" or can everything be done in a single VM?

Answer (score 0):

Minikube may be what you are looking for:

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube

The minikube tool spins up a VM which it configures to run a single-node version of kubernetes. From the VM host you can use kubernetes cli tools like kubectl to deploy containers into the single-node kubernetes running in the VM.

There is another tool called kompose:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose

which can help translate docker-compose.yml files into kubernetes resource files, suitable for use by kubectl.